# Is it possible to stop sending packages by particular host?

Tags: unix, server, ip, host, hazelcast

I see that some host_IP try connect using multicast to hazlecast cache.

com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.MulticastService
WARNING: [host_IP]:5709 [my_server] [3.6.1] Received a JoinRequest with a different packet version! This -> 4, Incoming -> 19, Sender -> /host_IP

Can u let me what is the problem ? Why host_IP send packages to my_server ?
IS it possible to stop sending packages by host_IP ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to update the group credentials in your `hazelcast.xml`. That is what differentiates different clusters running in the same Multicast.

```
<group>
    <name>group-name</name>
    <password>group-password</password>
</group>
```

If you are using default xml that comes in the jar, then you would have to update the group credentials using code after instantiating the `HazelcastInstance`.

```
hzInstance.getConfig().getGroupConfig().setName("group-name").setPassword("group-password");
```